# Set attribute from Polymer object property value

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have element and I put in it object with data for it.

```
<my-element data="{{item.content}}"></my-element>
```

For now I have not done this so I have all in `data` property declaration.

```
properties: {
  data: {
    type: Object,
    value: {
      active: false,
      name: "Some name."
      ...
   }
  }
}
```

I also have to click handler on child element which should toggle the boolean value.

```
_handleClickBlock: function () {
  this.data.active = !this.data.active;
}
```

I need to set `[active] attribute` on my-element to `data.active` value and make changes every time, because I use it in my CSS styles like `:host[active] ...`.

How can I achieve it? I tried `this.setAttribute('active', this.data.active)` in event handler, but it change the value only once; console log was toggling.

**Edit:**

I have tried use this code:

```
observers: [
    '_activeChange(data.active)'
],

_activeChange: function(newValue) {
    this.active = newValue;
    console.log("change");
},

_handleClickBlock: function () {
    console.log("------ click");
    this.data.active = !this.data.active;
    console.log(this.data.active);
}
```

But in my console output is only this, so observer is not called.

```
------ click
false
------ click
true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try including 'active' as a property in you my-element and set reflectToAttribute to true.

```
properties: {
  data:{...}
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    reflectToAttribute: true
  }
}
observers: [
  '_activeChange(data.active)'
],
_activeChange: function(newValue) {
  this.active = newValue;
}
```

Edit: Please go through how to change the path such that observers are notified. You need to update data.active as below

```
this.set('data.active', !this.data.active);
```

Below jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/qupoja/4/edit?html,output

Comment: I have added edit to my question. I tried this solution before, but 'observers' seems not work. It works only once on page load.